# 2002 chevy impala 3.8 won't shift into overdrive check engine light is not on

Tags: chevrolet, transmission, shifting, impala

I don't have a picture. Scanner tool has no codes showing. However, it did say vacuum leak test failed. I've changed gas cap, cleaned mass airflow sensor, and replaced fuel pressure vacuum harness that hooks into the throttle body and on the fuel rail.

Comment: What do you mean by overdrive? Do you mean it doesn't downshift when you push the pedal down a lot?

Comment: Check transmission fluid? I think the tranny problem is unrelated to the vacuum error, but obviously you should fix that anyway

Comment: It won't shift into overdrive it seems to sound like it's revved real high n rpms act like it shifts but it does not

Comment: @TracyEvans, So, cruising on the highway, for instance, your RPMs are high, like the transmission has not shifted into the highest gear?

Comment: Have you checked the transmission fluid level? Did you check the accuracy of the shift selector (is it actually in another position other than "D")?

Comment: Can you provide any codes, and verify that OD doesn't work with a scantool?